# Constant java:comp not bound in this context error tomcat6

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I keep getting this error and have tried a number of fixes rumoured online to no avail.

Here is the exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:comp is not bound in this Context
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at my.app.database.DatabaseManager.connect(DatabaseManager.java:44)
    at my.app.database.DatabaseManager.return(DatabaseManager.java:133)
    at my.app.GenParse.GeneratePastPositions.updateSatHistory(GeneratePastPositions.java:89)
    at my.app.updateHistory.run(SatelliteEclipseServer.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My resource is declared in `context.xml` as this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context reloadable="true">

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->
     <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="myUsername" password="myPassword" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://mysql.myServer.com:3306/myUserName"/>


</Context>
```

And the connection in my java code:

```
public void connect() throws SQLException, NamingException{
    initCtx = new InitialContext();
    envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");         
}
```

I think also due to this its not closing the connection like it should. Other than the error message its all working, but I think this error compounds over time and uses up all the available connections.

I'd really appreciate some help with this as its been annoying me for weeks!

Comment: What is your Tomcat version? Did you enable logging in Tomcat in order to see that in really processes your `context.xml` and tries to register your resource?

Comment: Its Tomcat6. I have default logging on. What should I be looking for to see that its been registered properly?

Comment: Not default, enable debug or trace. You should see that resouce is processed.